# SearchHits.getTotalHits() is not giving exact number of documents in ElasticSearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I want to use `SearchHits.getTotalHits()` to get the total number of documents matching request. However, I found that the value obtained by `SearchHits.getTotalHits()` was not equal to the sum of `SearchHits.getHits().length`. Is it normal?

```
SearchHits searchHits = response.getHits();
int total = (int)searchHits.getTotalHits();
int k = 0;
do {
    for (SearchHit hit : searchHits.getHits()) {
        k++;
    }
    response = esClient.prepareSearchScroll(response.getScrollId())
            .setScroll(scrollKeepAliveTime)
            .get();
} while (response.getHits().getHits().length != 0);
Assert.assertEquals(total, k);
```

- output

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<515> but was:<600>
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that you're always iterating on `searchHits`, i.e. the results of the very first query.

You need to reassign `searchHits` to `response.getHits()` after each scroll request, like this:

```
SearchHits searchHits = response.getHits();
int total = (int)searchHits.getTotalHits();
int k = 0;
do {
    for (SearchHit hit : searchHits.getHits()) {
        k++;
    }
    response = esClient.prepareSearchScroll(response.getScrollId())
            .setScroll(scrollKeepAliveTime)
            .get();
    searchHits = response.getHits();               <-- add this line
} while (searchHits.getHits().length != 0);        <-- modify this line
Assert.assertEquals(total, k);
```